# I'm unable to get date with a variable

Tags: python, date, integer

```
def get_next_monday(year, month, day):
    date0 = datetime.date(year, month, day)
    next_monday = date0 + datetime.timedelta(7 - date0.weekday() or 7)
    return next_monday

date2 = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y, %m, %d")
findnextweek = get_next_monday(date2)
```

If I replace `(year, month, day)` with `(date2)` I get Integer required. Otherwise, I get a different error

> TypeError: get_next_monday() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

Comment: Am I missing a question?

Comment: Looks like you are passing a string to the `get_next_monday` function, but it is expecting 3 individual parameters - not one string.

Answer (score 2):

You have some little problems in your code. Here's the fix and explanation:

```
import datetime

def get_next_monday(year, month, day):

    # if you want to accept str and int, you must convert the strings

    date0 = datetime.date(int(year), int(month), int(day))
    next_monday = date0 + datetime.timedelta(7 - date0.weekday() or 7)
    return next_monday


# you must convert the date in a list, because `get_next_monday` takes 3 arguments.
initial_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y, %m, %d").split(',')

# you must un-pack the date
findnextweek = get_next_monday(*initial_date)

print(findnextweek)
```

Note that normally you should be calling `get_next_monday` with something like `get_next_monday(2016, 6, 10)` or `get_next_monday('2016', '6', '10')`.

There's no much sense of creating datetime object, converting it in to an string, then a list, and finally re-converting in to a datetime object.

Anyways I hope it help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a string value to your `get_next_monday` function but it is expecting 3 arguments.

```
date2 = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y, %m, %d")
```

This will return a string similar to this: `'2016, 06, 28'`.
You'll want to split that string into 3 variables in order to pass it to your function.

There are many ways to do this but I'll provide a super simple option:

```
year, month, day = date2.split(',')
```

This will populate `year` with "2016", month with " 06" and day with " 28". You can then pass these three variables to your `get_next_monday` function. Don't forget to convert the arguments to numbers before passing them to the `date` function:

```
datetime.date( int(year), int(month), int(day) )
```

As you can see, the [split function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) takes a string as an input and "breaks" the string up into parts. It will "break" the string every time it sees a "," character because that is the argument we are passing to the `split` function. In our example, the strings will still include some spaces - you could use [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) to remove them, or you could change the date format to not have spaces: `strftime("%Y,%m,%d")`.